# Firebird /verysilent does not install the guardian

Tags: inno-setup, firebird, silent-installer

I have used the FB Setup 2.5.2.26540 with the following switches :

```
/SP- /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOCANCEL /COMPONENTS="ServerComponet\SuperServerComponent,ServerComponent,DevAdminComponent,ClientComponent" /NOGDS32 /FORCE
```

the documentation said:

```
Use the /MERGETASKS parameter instead if you want to
keep the default set of tasks and only select/deselect some of them.
By default the following tasks are run:
   UseGuardianTask
   UseServiceTask
   AutoStartTask
   InstallCPLAppletTask
   MenuGroupTask
   CopyFbClientAsGds32Task
```

so how to install fb with the default tasks i tried /MERGETASKS without any results, i don't need/want to copy gds32.dll nor fbclient.dll to system32...

Comment: You don't actually need the guardian, as this can be handled by default recovery functionality of Windows Services.

Comment: You can use `/TASKS="..."` and specify the tasks you do want executed, see http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline

Comment: i don't know about the default recovery functionality of Windows Services but i think  it's the guardian responsibilities to restart the server when it crash for some reasons....

Comment: The guardian is a left-over from pre-Windows 2000 era, and the normal recovery functionality of Windows Services does exactly that: restart Firebird if it crashed.

Comment: in that case no need to worry thank's

Comment: There are two cases for using guardian. Either you run Windows NT 4.0 (not sure FB 2.5 supports it) or you use FB Server as an application (not service).